# Add certain "command" multiple times

Tags: java, list, linked-list, integer

So I am working with lists right now. Lets say I have this.first.next to refer to the list cell after the first list cell. And lets say I have an int value at the beginning. If the int value is x=2 the this.first.next would change to this.first.next.next if the value was 3 this.first.next.next.next and so on how do I do this?

I hope you get what I am saying English aint my first language.

Comment: Based on the value of x, you loop that many times, but ensure not to go beyond when end of list arrived at.

Comment: Share the code that you have attempted so far.